# how to get order details in method-renderer for redirect payment gateway

Tags: payment-gateway, magento-2.2.1

I'm using **Magento 2.2.1**
I'm trying to create a new module for a custom payment gateway, I have created the module. But I didn't get the order details where in the **method-renderer** file, there I'm using a js file to redirection of payment gateway.

How to retrieve data here??

Comment: Use observer to get order detail